# Serial Communication between Arduino and Python

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to establish a communication between Arduino and Python. I want to write int values as bytes from arduino and read them in Python but i need some help to do that.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
long prev = millis();

void setup(){
Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop(){
 long current = millis(); 
  if(current - prev > 5000){
     Serial.write(32760); 
     prev = millis();
  }
}
```

And here is my Python code:

```
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 115200)
while True:
    data = arduino.read(); 
    print("number: ", int(data.encode('hex'),16));
```

The output in Python side is, `('number: ', 63736)` which is not as expected.

I have tried to print it by using `ord()` function but nothing worked.
Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.